# Multifield rich text values not getting restore when open dialog

Tags: dialog, aem

I have multifield richtext  in my dialog.When i try to author it the value will get author properly But when i open dialog again the value wont be there in dialog.Can some one share multifield js.My multifielfd dialog contains richtext,path,text?

Comment: First of all, show us some code. Are you using default component or you wrote your own?

Comment: http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/07/aem-61-touch-ui-composite-multifield-with-rich-text-editor-rte.html?m=1 this link has a sample component with touchui multifield with richtext. I had also modified the library to support a different use case in last comment. Please check if this is helpful

Comment: I want it for classic ui dialog

Comment: For classicui multifield is straight forward. You may need to check ACS multifield panel. It supports most xtypes in classicui. https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/widgets.html. One more example is available here as well: http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/06/aem-61-classic-ui-composite-multifield-storing-values-as-nodes.html
If you can share code we can help out what has gone wrong.